# In ASP.Net, will radio buttons in the same group change Checked state automaticlly?

Tags: c#, asp.net, radio-button

There are 2 radio buttons in the same group on the page:

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" GroupName="Group1"/>
<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton2" runat="server" GroupName="Group1"/>
```

In the code behined, I write the code to check both radio buttons:

```
RadioButton1.Checked = true;
RadioButton2.Checked = true;
```

I thought the `RadioButton1.Checked` will be `false` because they are in the same group, when I check the second one, the first one will automaticlly uncheck. But actually, they are both `Checked=true`.

In my application, there is a switch-case like this:

```
// Some code to check the default RadioButton

switch(val){
  case 1:
    RadioButton1.Checked = true;
  case 2:
    RadioButton2.Checked = true;
}
```

So sometimes both radio buttons' `Checked` will be true. That's odd, so I changed the code to:

```
switch(val){
  case 1:
    RadioButton1.Checked = true;
    RadioButton2.Checked = false;
  case 2:
    RadioButton1.Checked = false;
    RadioButton2.Checked = true;
}
```

This works fine but what if I need add 10 more radio buttons, write a long list of =true, =false .....?

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rather than a `switch` statement, you'd probably be better off with:

```
RadioButton1.Checked = (val == 1);
RadioButton2.Checked = (val == 2);
RadioButton3.Checked = (val == 3);
// and so on ...
RadioButton10.Checked = (val == 10);
```

This way, everything gets set to `false` *except* for the `RadioButton` equal to `val`.  If you had a *huge* amount of `RadioButton` controls, maybe you'd want to put them in an array and loop through that instead.

Answer (score 1):

Assign groupname property to both the radiobuttons controls.
Radio buttons need to have identical  group name property  , if not they behave as checkboxes .